# I need to find a suitable list which defies the function

Tags: python

> In this quiz, we aren't asking you to solve problems. Instead, you are
>   given some problems and their incorrect solutions, and your task is to
>   find tests where these solutions actually work incorrectly — by
>   returning incorrect answer, working for too long, crashing, taking too
>   much memory — anything that would give a verdict other than
>   "Accepted". Consider that the time limit is 2 seconds, and the memory
>   limit is 256 megabytes for all of the following problems.
>
> This exercise will help you imagine tests for your own code. And it's
>   actually very similar to "challenges" on many competitive programming
>   platforms (e.g. Topcoder, Codeforces) — where after solving a problem
>   you could earn additional score by breaking other's solutions to it.
>   We hope you'll like it!
>
> Next follows the first problem and the incorrect solution to it.
>
> You are given a non-empty list of integers, and you need to find the
>   maximum value among them. The length of the list is not greater than
>   100, and the absolute value of each element is not greater than 1000.
>
> ```
>  def solve(a):
>   max = 0
>   for x in a:
>     if x > max:
>       max = x
>   return max
> ```
>
> Implement a function called getTest. It should return a list on which
>   the solve function works incorrectly. Note that the returned list must
>   fit the restrictions in the statement.
>
> The function is to be implemented in Python 3, but if you don't know
>   this language, it's no problem — the sample code should give you the
>   idea of how to do what you need.

```
    def getTest():
  return [1,2,3];
```

I need to find the list where solve function fails but I am unable to do it since I am new to programming. Can anyone help me understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Since this smells like homework, I'll give you a hint rather than the full solution. You don't need to worry about being new to programming, you can figure this out without writing a single line of code :-)

In their "solution", they make an assumption about the values in the list that may not always hold. Can you figure out what this assumption is?

Answer (score -1):

```py
def getTest():
    return [-1]*100
```

This will make sure it can't find the max value and it will also return 0.

Comment: Although just so you know a lot of people can get pretty salty if you don't provide code that you've written to try and solve the problem already. A little heads up for the future.

Comment: You should NOT post full working code when answering homework questions - it totally defeats the whole point of homework.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I know that but the OP said they have very little programming knowledge so I thought just to help I'll do it. Also I did mention how when posting an question on here you should provide examples of code you've already tried as a heads up.

Comment: You didn't help, quite on the contrary actually - the whole point of homework is to solve the question by oneself, else you don't learn much. And this particular problem requires very few programming knowledge FWIW, just very basic math skills and some logic.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Honestly homework is pretty useless and everything you learn and practice should be done during school hours anyway. Also please don't down vote or 'shame' an answer just because I was helping someone with their homework. I still mentioned that in the future they should try to solve the problem before posting so there you go.

Comment: I totally disagree with each and every point of your above comment, and I'll keep on downvoting every answer I see that provide full solution to homework question, explaining why I downvoted (which has nothing to do with "shaming"). Case closed as far as I'm concerned.